# How is this $f(n) = n^n$ function called?

Tags: functions

If $n^2$ is called quadratic function,$n^3$ is called cubic function then what is name for $n^n$ ? exponential

Comment: I don't think the function is important enough to have earned a commonly-used name.

Comment: they'd probably call it an n-ic!  Or not..  I agree with Gerry

Comment: c2h50h, personally I think it is more important what you can do with this type of function. Do you know its derivative? Do you know at which point it "starts" on the y-axis? Do you know it has an absolute minimum? Can you calculate that minimum? These are all very interesting questions regarding the graph of this function.

Comment: If this function is restricted to natural numbers $n$, then $f(n)$ counts the number of functions from an $n$-element set to itself. In that case, I think you could reasonably just invent a name for it, like the "self-map function". This function and close relatives actually do crop up often in combinatorics, especially in connection with the combinatorics of trees, and so I somewhat disagree with earlier comments on the relative importance. However, I've never heard a name attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = x^x$ is an exponential type function, but note that also the functions $f(x) = 1^x, f(x) = \left(\frac12\right)^x$ are exponential type function. And if you want to find a specific name for that function, I think you'll not achieve much success.